# Why every function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is proper?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I am trying to self-study the textbook "An Introduction to Convexity, Optimization, and Algorithms" by Walaa M. Moursi. In part 3.1 she states that:

> $f$ is called *proper* if $dom(f) \neq \emptyset$ and every $x \in X$ satisfies $-\infty < f(x)$.

Keep in mind that, in this book, $X$ stands for Euclidean space. Also, she defines (effective) domain to be:

> $dom(f) := \{x \in X \mid f(x) < +\infty \}$

Then she gives an example of proper functions and says:

> Any function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is proper.

And this is where I don't understand what is going on. For example, define $f := -\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}$, then by her definition $dom(f) = \mathbb{R}$, but $f(0) = -\infty$, so $f$ is clearly not proper. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Explanation: $dom(f)$ is not $\mathbb R\,.$ It is $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\,.$

Comment: I don't have the book, but $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are pretty much never considered to be elements of $\mathbb{R}$. So what you defined is now a function $X\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KurtG. why though? by the definition if $f(x) < +\infty$, then x is in the domain. $f(0)=-\infty < +\infty$ so $0 \in dom(f)$

Comment: @Mark I don't understand what you mean by "So what you defined is now a function $X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$."

Comment: @Mark ahhh, I got what you mean! you mean my function is $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. you are right; I should have noticed that $\mathbb{R}$ implies finiteness. Thank you.

Comment: No. You mix up range and domain. The range is $\mathbb R$. This excludes $0$ from the domain.

Comment: @Hamed Sorry, I meant "not a function $X\to\mathbb{R}$". It's not a function because the value at $x=0$ is not a real number.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this book uses a highly nonstandard definition of properness for functions.

Comment: The function $f$ you have defined is a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$, if one defines $f(0) = -\infty$. Since $-\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$, it is not proper.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It depends on you background. This is indeed the 'standard' definition used in convex analysis and optimization. As I learned right now, in topology this term has a different - non-standard - definition :)